# Is the code correct? Nrf24l01

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, spi, nrf24l01+, joystick

I'm am a beginner, so I'm sorry I have written this wrong.

Is this piece of code correct? If not where?

Transmitter:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"

int* Msg, mSg, msG;

RF24 radio(9, 10);
const uint8_t pipe = 1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Msg = analogRead(A1);
  radio.write(Msg, sizeof(Msg));
  mSg = analogRead(A2);
  radio.write(mSg, sizeof(mSg));
  msG = analogRead(A3);
  radio.write(msG, sizeof(msG));
  delay(100);
}
```

Receiver:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"

#define in1 2
#define in2 3
#define in3 4
#define in4 5

#define in5 A2
#define in6 A3
#define in7 A4
#define in8 A5

const int maxMsgLength = 64;
char Msg[maxMsgLength];
const int maxmSgLength = 64;
char mSg[maxmSgLength];
const int maxmsGLength = 64;
char msG[maxmsGLength];

RF24 radio(9, 10);
const uint8_t pipe = 1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(Msg, maxMsgLength - 1);
    radio.read(mSg, maxmSgLength - 1);
    radio.read(msG, maxmsGLength - 1);
  }

  int xAxis = Msg;
  int yAxis = mSg;
  int YAxis = msG;

  if (xAxis < 450) {
    // Forward
    digitalWrite(in1, 1);
    digitalWrite(in2, 0);
    digitalWrite(in3, 1);
    digitalWrite(in4, 0);
    Serial.println("Forward");
  }
  else if (xAxis > 550) {
    // Backward
    digitalWrite(in1, 0);
    digitalWrite(in2, 1);
    digitalWrite(in3, 0);
    digitalWrite(in4, 1);
    Serial.println("Backward");
  }
  else {
    // Stop
    digitalWrite(in1, 0);
    digitalWrite(in2, 0);
    digitalWrite(in3, 0);
    digitalWrite(in4, 0);
    Serial.println("Stop");
  }

  if (yAxis < 450) {
    // Left
    digitalWrite(in5, 1);
    digitalWrite(in6, 0);
    Serial.println("Left");
  }
  else if (yAxis > 550) {
    // Right
    digitalWrite(in5, 0);
    digitalWrite(in6, 1);
    Serial.println("Right");
  }
  else {
    // Stop
    digitalWrite(in5, 0);
    digitalWrite(in6, 0);
    Serial.println("Stop");
  }

  if (yAxis < 450) {
    // Flipper Up
    digitalWrite(in7, 1);
    digitalWrite(in8, 0);
    Serial.println("Up");
  }
  else if (yAxis > 550) {
    // Flipper Down
    digitalWrite(in7, 0);
    digitalWrite(in8, 1);
    Serial.println("Down");
  }
  else {
    // Stop
    digitalWrite(in7, 0);
    digitalWrite(in8, 0);
    Serial.println("Mid");
  }
  delay(250);
}
```

Edit:

Transmitter:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"

int x, y, f;

RF24 radio(9, 10);
const uint8_t pipe = 1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  x = analogRead(A1);
  radio.write(x, sizeof(x));
  y = analogRead(A2);
  radio.write(y, sizeof(y));
  f = analogRead(A3);
  radio.write(f, sizeof(f));
  delay(100);
}
```

Receiver:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RF24.h"

#define in1 2
#define in2 3
#define in3 4
#define in4 5

#define in5 A2
#define in6 A3
#define in7 A4
#define in8 A5

int x;
int y;
int f;

RF24 radio(9, 10);
const uint8_t pipe = 1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (radio.available()) {
    radio.read(&x, sizeof(x));
    radio.read(&y, sizeof(y));
    radio.read(&f, sizeof(f));
  }

  if (x < 450) {
    // Forward
    digitalWrite(in1, 1);
    digitalWrite(in2, 0);
    digitalWrite(in3, 1);
    digitalWrite(in4, 0);
    Serial.println("Forward");
  }
  else if (x > 550) {
    // Backward
    digitalWrite(in1, 0);
    digitalWrite(in2, 1);
    digitalWrite(in3, 0);
    digitalWrite(in4, 1);
    Serial.println("Backward");
  }
  else {
    // Stop
    digitalWrite(in1, 0);
    digitalWrite(in2, 0);
    digitalWrite(in3, 0);
    digitalWrite(in4, 0);
    Serial.println("Stop");
  }
  if(x > 1023)x = 1023;
  if(x < 0)x = 0;

  if (y < 450) {
    // Left
    digitalWrite(in5, 1);
    digitalWrite(in6, 0);
    Serial.println("Left");
  }
  else if (y > 550) {
    // Right
    digitalWrite(in5, 0);
    digitalWrite(in6, 1);
    Serial.println("Right");
  }
  else {
    // Stop
    digitalWrite(in5, 0);
    digitalWrite(in6, 0);
    Serial.println("Stop");
  }
  if(y > 1023)y = 1023;
  if(y < 0)y = 0;

  if (f < 450) {
    // Flipper Up
    digitalWrite(in7, 1);
    digitalWrite(in8, 0);
    Serial.println("Up");
  }
  else if (f > 550) {
    // Flipper Down
    digitalWrite(in7, 0);
    digitalWrite(in8, 1);
    Serial.println("Down");
  }
  else {
    // Stop
    digitalWrite(in7, 0);
    digitalWrite(in8, 0);
    Serial.println("Mid");
  }
  if(f > 1023)f = 1023;
  if(f < 0)f = 0;

  Serial.println(x);
  Serial.println(y);
  Serial.println(f);
  delay(250);
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does it behave not the way you want? Because we don't know that. And if it does not behave like you want, describe exactly what you expect, and what you notice.

Comment: So, I want it to take the values from the joysticks and send it to the **receiver side.** There the **joystick values** must be taken and _l298n_ must behave accordingly. If the joystick is pulled upward then the motors should go forward and vice versa. Same with the x-axis, if the joystick is pulled on the left side the motor must rotate to the **left-hand side.**

Comment: Ok ... and does your program behave like that? If yes, why ask the question? If not, describe what you see and what you expect.

Comment: So the program does not behave like that.

Comment: The joystick values do not get transmitted and on the receiver, the values are displayed as 0.

Comment: Did you try a default RF24 example?

Comment: Yes, the default example is working fine.

Comment: Try removing the pointer (*) in int* Msg, mSg, msG;. In general, use print to print out all variables to pinpoint problems

Comment: Do you mean * <- this symbol.

Comment: Yes: remove that *

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Then try print statements.

Comment: According to the code, the Serial monitor of the receiver shows Stop, Left, and Up.

Comment: Can you please explain the transmission of integers with the rf24.

Comment: The error came that print is not member of the RF24 library.

Comment: I created an answer (doesn't mean all is ok, but should give you some advice and solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see (at least one ) problem.

First remove the * from:

```
int* Msg, mSg, msG;
```

Because it should store integers (numbers), not pointers to numbers.

Also, make the variables better. These almost identical names are quite confusing (name them x, y or z or a better name).

What you are doing is sending the 3 integers as integers (meaning that each integer is 2 bytes), so you send 6 bytes.

But in the receiver, you read characters, you have to replace this by:

- Changing `char`  to `int`  for the 3 variables in the receiver side
- Also here, change the names
- Remove the constants for the length (64)
- Instead read the code as you write it:

  int xAxis;
  radio.read(&xAxis, sizeof(int));

& means: address, the read function stores the value in xAxis (so you don't have to copy it afterwards).
Also print out the value after the read so you can check it.

Comment: Thank you this program does work. But even if the joysticks are in the middle the value shown in the serial monitor is Forward, Left, and Up(the first if statements in each argument). then too, the transmission glitches.

Comment: That depends on the values you get (did you check the values of x, y and zAxis?)

Comment: The values are coming insanely different

Comment: When the joystick is pulled upward the values go like 129, 0, 0 then 0, 129, 0 and then 0, 0, 129. But when it is pulled backward then the values are 16382, 0, -13872 and so.

Comment: Added if (x/y/f < 0)x/y/f = 0; and if (x/y/f > 1023)x/y/f = 1023;

Comment: Ok, also I think even then the radio communication is ok including parsing the data to variables ... So the only thing left (if not already solved) is the input from the joystick.

Comment: I tested the joystick inputs in another program just for printing the values of the joysticks. The default value of the joystick is 500 and the maximum is 1023 and the minimum is 0.

Comment: The values of the joystick are alright on the transmitter side. But I'm not sure of the receiver.

Comment: Thank you Michel. Now the code works just fine but it does glitch rarely. I forgot to add &x, &y, and &f in the transmitter.